# Data management-SQL

Tags: sql, database, h2

I'm trying to work on my data management project for my class but I am having trouble importing data on the server.

P.S.: I'm using H2 Console

```
CREATE TABLE SERVES AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD ('C:/Users/H/Downloads/SERVES.csv’);
```

Error:

> CREATE TABLE SERVES AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD
>   ('C:/Users/H/Downloads/SERVES.csv’);; Syntax error in SQL statement
>   "CREATE TABLE SERVES AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD
>   ([*]'C:/Users/H/Downloads/SERVES.csv’);"; SQL statement: CREATE TABLE
>   SERVES AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD ('C:/Users/H/Downloads/SERVES.csv’);
>   [42000-181] 42000/42000 (Help)

Comment: Are you sure this is related to MySQL?

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM CSVREAD ('C:/Users/H/Downloads/SERVES.csv’);` work on its own?

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong kind of quote character to *end* the string literal. You have used `’` instead of `'`. So instead of:

```
'C:/Users/H/Downloads/SERVES.csv’
```

use

```
'C:/Users/H/Downloads/SERVES.csv'
```

The very last character is slightly different.